# why does pandas handle subplot different for two dataframes vs. one dataframe?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

When I have two separate DataFrames and try to plot them in separate graphs using subplot, it doesn't work (I know, I should store the axis created by subplot and give that to the DataFrame):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([2, 4, 8], columns=['data1'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([3.2, 3.4, 3.3], columns=['data2'])
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
df1.plot()  # ignores the created subplot
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
df2.plot()  # ignores the created subplot
```

But strangely enough, if I gather the data into one DataFrame, then this syntax works

```
df1['data2'] = df2
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
df1['data1'].plot()  # now subplot is recognized and used!
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
df1['data2'].plot()  # now subplot is recognized and used!
```

Any idea why the second part uses the created subplot, while the first part doesn't? Just a coincidence? Or is there a reason?